# Making a webpage scraper using axios/cheerio; can't figure out the rest of the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

anyone with axios/cheerio experience can you answer this question please?

I'm trying to make a scraper but having difficulty making it get a selected `div`

the html section is like so:

```html
<div class="_702d723c dib w-50 bb b--black-10 pr2">
<h3 class="c84e15be f5 mt2 pt2 mb0 black-50">Version</h3>
<p class="f2874b88 fw6 mb3 mt2 truncate black-80 f4">7.3.2</p>
</div>
```

Scraper Code:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");
let NPMJS = `https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver`;

axios.get(NPMJS).then((response) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    $('._702d723c').filter(function () {
        var data = $(this);
        let version = data.children().first().next().text()
        console.log(version)
    })
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

outputs:

```yaml
7.3.2
ISC
83.8 kB
51
github.com/npm/node-semver#readme
Gitgithub.com/npm/node-semver
6 months ago
```

How would I get the `7.2.3` from this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class looks like it might change. I would do:

```
$('h3:contains("Version") + p').text()
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to test this theory out, but will let you know when I do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('._702d723c').each(function (i, e) {
  console.log($(e).find("p").html());
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to test this theory out, but will let you know when I do.